# NodeJS and MariaDB, Placeholder inside Queries

Tags: sql, node.js, mariadb, placeholder

I'm pretty new to Mariadb.
I want to execute a Insert statement with placeholders for the values but also for the columns. I've tried the ? and the ?? for the columns but still getting the Error, that sql syntax is wrong:

```
let query = "INSERT INTO Users(??, ??, ??, ??, ??) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);"
let data = [ 'email','forename', 'location','longitude','latitude', 
         ,'test','test','test',1,1 ]
conn.query(query, data)
```

What is wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the only not supported things compare to mysql connector is those ["Escaping query identifiers"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers).

The reasons are :

- First, i don't see the use case for that. Is there any !?
- I would prefer to have standard MariaDB SQL syntax with only `?` as placeholder.

The reason to have only `?` as a placeholder is that when connector will be using binary protocol (not yet implemented) connector won't have to parse the SQL command, then perform better.

But you can rewrite the command as :

```
let query = "INSERT INTO Users(`email`,`forename, `location`,`longitude`,`latitude`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);"
let data = ['test','test','test',1,1]
conn.query(query, data)
```

If you see some use case for that. feel free to create an issue on [github](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-nodejs)

Comment: I have a lot of different tables with optional fields. My idea was that I don't have build a query for every possible option. To keep the prevention of SQL Injection, i wanted to count how many of the columns wants the user to update and then first build the query with placeholders

Comment: could you create an issue on https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-nodejs then to discuss this ?

Comment: Of course there is are use cases for it! I have a straight forward one myself right now. An endpoint for updating settings; it wants a setting ID and a value. The IDs are mapped, or direct names of fields in the table, and the value is the value. There have certainly got to be many other valid scenarios where code would be much much elegant with such support.